# Came back TO the U.K or Came back IN the UK?

Tags: prepositions

What the correct preposition here:

> I Came back **TO** the U.K last year from a holiday

or

> Came back **IN** the UK last year from a holiday.

Comment: `to` -- it's the destination. `I came back in a canoe,` would make grammatical sense, if not practical.

Comment: Why are you considering *in* to indicate motion? Your question should include your rationale, not just "choose one".